# update from external storage

Tags: rom-update

I am trying to update system to either Android 5.0 lillipop or Android 4.4 KitKat. I formated sd card to FAT32, and moved rom there. 
 When in recovery I used `apply update from external storage`  
  `failed to verify whole-file signature` 
 `signature verification failed`
I downloaded both roms [from here](http://www.idroidspace.com/download-android-5-0-lollipop-gapps-for-custom-roms/)
the same thing happened for second rom.
I am using Onetouch EVO7.

if this may help recovery says `recovery system v4.00`

Also I can not use fastboot to connect with device (waiting for device), so I am using adb instead. Device is rooted using kingo root

Comment: The link refers to [GApps](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) package which do not contain any ROM but only the apps developed by Google which may not be present if you install a Custom ROM. You need to (unlock bootloader, if the device has bootloader locked) then install custom recovery(some devices do not allow installing custom ROM from stock recovery) and then flash/install a Custom ROM and flash GApps package at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ROMS' you have downloaded are actually just the Google Apps that would come with a stock ROM.

> Every new Android Smartphone comes with various pre-installed apps such as Gmail, Google Play Store, Google Chrome, etc., which are referred as Google proprietary apps or specifically Gapps. These apps are developed under Google Licensing terms in order to prevent usage in any other mobile operating system and modification by the third-party developers. This is the reason that you can’t get your hands-on any of the Gapps after installing Custom ROMs.

The site you linked to is providing these apps in a way that allows you to easily add them to a custom ROM you already have on your device. It is not providing the custom ROM. You will need to look elsewhere for this as they are specific to each device model.